# How do I find what causes a blank white screen in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, xampp

Am trying to build a test environment for a WordPress project using xamp.

Apache is listening on localhost:8080 
MySQL is 3306 root with no password

Changes did in wp-config
Dbname is wp-db
Dbhost is locallhost:8080
Dbuser is root

WordPress root folder is in c:/xamp/htdocs/wordpress

Before changing the dbhost from local host to localhost:8080 I was getting a "error establishing connection to database" now am jus getting a full white screen.

Please advise. A million thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

White screens are usually PHP errors. Try Debug and see what PHP errors you are getting. You may simply have an error in wp-config.php or are missing a core WordPress file or folder.

Add

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

in wp-config.php and the debug.log file will be in wp-content.

Add this line

`define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);`

to wp-config.php to log and dump them to the browser.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: Thanks mate. Will try it out. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have introduced a PHP syntax error when you were changing your `wp-config.php` - check the xampp PHP logs (**edit** see @markratledge's answer for more details on tracking down the error).  After that, you were closer to the right setup when you saw the "error establishing connection to database" message, so in `wp-config.php`

1. Change the DB_HOST back to `localhost` (no port, as it seemed to work before)
2. Set your DB_USER to (eg) `wpdbuser`
3. Set your DB_PASSWORD to (eg) `password` (choose something more secure if the database is accessible externally)

If you haven't already, create your empty database by running the following in MySQL (WordPress won't create the database for you, you need to do that):

```
CREATE DATABASE `wp-db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Also in MySQL, create the user with the details you specified in `wp-config.php`:

```
create user 'wpdbuser'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
```

Finally, make sure your dedicated database user can create the WordPress tables:

```
grant all privileges on wp-db.* to wpdbuser@localhost;
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Extremely detailed explanation, appreciate it.